# How to determine altitude of a given co ordinate

Tags: javascript, here-api

I need to determine altitude from a given co ordinate.
As specified [here](http://api.maps.nokia.com/2.1.1/apireference/symbols/nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate.html). I believe there is an option for getting altitude from a given co ordinate. I tried below code

```
 var v = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(39.0997,-94.5768); 
 alert(v.altitude);
```

Whatever co ordinate i supply it gives me back "undefined".

also there is a concept called "altmode". I didn't get any clue if there any connection exists between my problem and "altmode" due to lack of examples.
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API does not provide mechanisms for automatically determining altitudes at any given lat/lon. It only provides facilities to add altitudes to coordinates. By default, if you do not specify altitudes, it is undefined.

You will have to use some elevation web service to determine altitudes at your specified locations.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. So is this some kind of disadvantage using HERE map api? As far as I know, google map services already have a altitude finder. Oh yes here[link](http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-find-altitude.htm) it is. But at the same time i can not use google and here map services together. Any alternatives or options with here maps? Maybe I should look out for more answer for sometime.